# Como expor apenas algumas colunas da tabela em um WebService via SOAP?

Tags: c#, web-service, soap

Como fazer pra expor apenas algumas colunas de em um WebService ? 
Exemplo:

Preciso expor apenas o **Nome** e **SobreNome** da tabela:

```
public class Cliente 
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public string SobreNome {get; set;}
   public string CPF {get; set;}
}

[WebMethod]
public Cliente RetrieveDevice(Cliente Cliente)
{
    Cliente cli = new Cliente();
    Negocio objNegocio = new Negocio();
    cli = objNegocio.getCliente(Cliente);
    return cli;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso usando o atributo `[XmlIgnore()]` sobre a propriedade que você não deseja que seja serializada, no caso a propriedade CPF:

```
public class Cliente 
{
   public string Nome {get; set;}
   public string SobreNome {get; set;}

   [XmlIgnore()]
   public string CPF {get; set;}
}
```